# Is it possible to add a semicolon in TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to add a semicolon in a TextInput field so the input text is split up?

I don't mean just a placeholder, I want it there permanently. I guess I could use two TextInput fields but I'd rather use one.

I want to make an input field that holds time, like 00:00.

```
             <TextInput
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                maxLength={4}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={sample=> props.textChange(sample)}
                value={props.sample}
                onKeyPress={props.sample}
            />
```

I know I could do something like this, but I want to avoid it.

```
        <View style={styles.sampleContainer}>
            <TextInput
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                maxLength={2}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={sample1 => props.textChange(sample1)}
                value={props.sample1}
                onKeyPress={props.sample}
            />
            <View style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'black', borderTopWidth: 1 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>:</Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                maxLength={2}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={sample2 => props.textChange(sample2)}
                value={props.sample2}
                onKeyPress={props.sample}
            />
        </View>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But we need you to make an attempt - we can help you get that attempt to work but we won't do it for you.

Comment: I mean there's definitely more than one way to go about this. It all depends on how you want the user to provide their input. Do you actually want them to type in the time?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes, I want them to type in their time for instance, 3:40 in one TextInput. The output value would be 340, but the input would be in two sections in one TextInput.

Comment: I don't want to brag but there is a ton of articles and projects out there that do exactly what you're asking

Comment: Easy, use two inputs then make it *look* like one using CSS.

Comment: @KevinB "I guess I could use two TextInput fields but I'd rather use one."

Comment: Formatting solutions are going to be quite... well, difficult to work with. If you start screwing with what's in the input while the user is using it, you add having to deal with controlling what is selected and where the insertion point is. It's not impossible, it's just a lot more complicated than simply having two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that just formats the input in the `onChange` function.  However the symbol/colon is not permanent, as to have it there when there is no input would mean filling the input with spaces, so you couldn't start typing at the beginning of the value.  To have the colon there permanently you'd need to write a function that would zero-fill any value that's not of the appropriate length:

```
const FormattedInput = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const formattedValue = formatInput(e.target.value);
    if (formattedValue.length < 6) {
      setValue(formattedValue);
    }
  }

  const formatInput = (input) => {
    if (input.length > 2 && input[2] !== ":") {
      return input.substring(0, 2) + ":" + input.slice(2);
    }
    return input;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input placeholder="00:00" type="text" onChange={onChange} value={value}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/OJLEKXN).